# react native error while trying to run android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

yarn android
yarn run v1.22.18
$ react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
> Android gradle plugin: 7.3.1
> Gradle: 7.5.1

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
106 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 99 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\M\Documents\GitHub\ztap-reviews\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:41: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.olaspagym.app:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
> error: failed processing manifest.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\M\Documents\GitHub\ztap-reviews\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:41: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.olaspagym.app:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
> error: failed processing manifest.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\M\Documents\GitHub\ztap-reviews\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\M\Documents\GitHub\ztap-reviews\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\M\Documents\GitHub\ztap-reviews\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\M\Documents\GitHub\ztap-reviews\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

having this error while trying to run "yarn android"
the project was working perfectly on other PC (MacOS) and now I am on a different PC (Windows 10)
React Version : 18.2.0
React Native : 0.71.3